# Zend framework recurring dependency

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 we use the factories to initiate classes. For the factories we make use off the `FactoryInterface`, which gives you the ability to use the ServiceManager.

Our problems only is with recurring dependency. We have te following

We have the `PlaceRepository` and `PlaceEntity`.

The `PlaceRepostory` is dependend of the `PlaceEntity` so it knows which entity it needs to return. However the `PlaceEntity` also needs the `PlaceRepostory` so it can get a parent place. (like get the country of city x (where both city and country are a place)).

This ends in an forever going dependency.

Now we could inject the service locator in the entity but you loose the ability for easy testing and you can't see of which class it is depended on.

So is there an other option for this or beter option to this problem, so you can still have the dependency but it is not recurring like an inity loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dependancy is hierarchical split it into ownership and membership.
 Try adding object properties which point to members and owner.
 Since PlaceRepository owns PlaceEntity objects you can implement like that

```
instancePlaceRepository->members['instancePlaceEntityName'] = instancePlaceEntity;
```

and

```
instancePlaceEntity->owner = instancePlaceRepository;
```

Which will put everything in order.

You can walk down the members and climb up the owners.

If you have Country->City->Street type dependancies which, everything is placeEntity and a single placeRepository holds everything then eliminate ownership of PlaceRepository,
this time build the hierarchy around the places. Country->members have cities and towns and cities->members  have streets, buildings etc